# Finding Defined Media Queries with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

My challenge here is to search a webpage to attempt to find all of the defined page breakpoints, eg media queries. I don't want to find just media queries currently being applied, but all of the defined media queries in the CSS file.

I've done a bit of browsing but so far I've had absolutely no luck. I know it's possible as libraries like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/respond.src.js) must do it, but having looked at the source I'm not entirely sure how they're doing it or the best way to go about it.

Any advice is much appreciated,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, you may try to parse `<link>` tags, grab url to `.css` file and request them via AJAX (if in the same domain), once you've received body of `.css` file you can parse it and find media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which respond.js does this is loading the css file itself and not rely on what the DOM exposes to JavaScript.
The browsers all support other things and even the things they support they don't always expose.
For instance Internet Explorer only exposes regular styleRules (no @imports or anything like that).
So don't go into that direction.

I would advise a way similar to respond.js' and get the media queries that way.

Hope it helps, PM5544...